# Android WebViewClient / WebViewAssetLoader implementation error

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to load a webpage in asset folder and app's local storage using the webasset loader using the code provided by google.

```
    final WebViewAssetLoader assetLoader = new WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
                .addPathHandler("/assets/", new WebViewAssetLoader.AssetsPathHandler(this))
                .build();

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            @RequiresApi(21)
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                                              WebResourceRequest request) {
                return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.getUrl());
            }
//This gives the error: shouldInterceptRequest(WebView, WebResourceRequest)' is already
   defined in 'Anonymous class derived from android.webkit.WebViewClient

            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // for API < 21
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                                              WebResourceRequest request) {
                return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(Uri.parse(request));
//This gives an error for the request variable. It says : Required type: String and
   Provided: WebResourceRequest. When I cast it as a string type, it
   gives an error similar to first error.
            }
        });
```

Can someone please guide me here? What am i doing wrong here, i am using the exact code given by google. Any tutorial on using this class?

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you found in the documentation is wrong, and I have already opened an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179800052) for it.

The problem is that the second method's signature, which refers to a deprecated implementation, should instead be:

```java
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
```

Use this and it'll compile (and work) as expected.